# Repository or university working paper series

Tags: preprint, repository

I am from the field of economics and preprints are ok with econ journals. I just cannot understand what is the difference between repository (like ArXiv) and publishing results in some working paper series?

I read somewhere that repository assigns DOI and working paper does not. Also, it is possible to update the repository's version, and I am not sure about working papers. From another point of view, working papers might be registered to more databases and make one's research more visible to the public....

So what are the main pros/cons in publishing preliminary results in a repository and in working papers (or discussion papers series??)? What are the differences?

Comment: You might need to inquire with whoever handles your working paper series, but in my experience the two aren't mutually exclusive. At least in maths its quite common for preprints to be both put on arXiv, as well as in the local preprint series. Although that seems to lead to the latter slowly dying out.

Comment: What do you mean by _working paper series_?

Comment: for instance, Working Papers European University Institute, or Working Papers *any university*

Answer (score 2):

People actively follow arXiv. They subscribe to the RSS feeds, mailing lists, Twitter bots, etc. that inform them about recent relevant preprints that appear on arXiv. Google Scholar finds new papers on arXiv quickly, and this way the authors will get quick notifications when something that cites their work appears on arXiv. ArXiv papers are also indexed in other widely-used databases (e.g. DBLP in computer science).

I don't see any reason to use a local working paper series. In terms of visibility, it doesn't sound much better than e.g. simply hiding the paper somewhere on your personal home page and hoping that Google will eventually index it and someone will accidentally find it that way.

Comment: (+1) Especially for your second paragraph. I was about to write a comment saying essentially the same thing before seeing your answer. I don't know about economics (but I wouldn't expect it to be much different), but with arXiv you have papers all grouped at one internet location and sorted by field. I'd have to look at hundreds of university sites in well over 30 countries to be on the lookout for papers dealing with topics of interest to me, and if I wanted others to see something of mine, I certainly wouldn't stick it in some local place that few would think to (or care to) look in.